Changing the x axis to logarithmic in the function forest_model
I've fitted this logistic model:
model <- glm(Groupe~Cluster+age, family="binomial",data= base)

And I'd like to present the results as a forest plot using this code:
forest_model(model, exponentiate=TRUE)

But I'd like the x-axis scale to be logarithmic, which I can't manage to do.
Thanks for your help or other alternatives.

If you're willing to forego all of the annotation, dotwhisker::dwplot() or sjPlot::plot_model() will give you coefficient plots

One potential option is to 'capture' the figure using the ggplotify package then transform the x axis via the ggplot2 scale_x_continuous() function, e.g.
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("forestmodel")
library(forestmodel)
library(ggplotify)

# example data
cohort <- data.frame(Age = c(43, 39, 34, 55, 70, 59, 44, 83, 76, 44, 
                             75, 60, 62, 50, 44, 40, 41, 42, 37, 35, 55, 46), 
                     Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                       levels = c("1","2"), class = "factor"))

age.glm <- glm(Age ~ Group, data = cohort)
forest_plot <- forest_model(age.glm, exponentiate=TRUE)
#> Resized limits to included dashed line in forest panel
forest_plot



forest_ggplot <- as.ggplot(forest_plot)
forest_ggplot +
  scale_x_continuous(transform = "pseudo_log", limits = c(0.1,2.2))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.


Created on 2024-04-30 with reprex v2.1.0
You may need to tweak the limits to get your desired figure size. Does this approach work with your actual data?
